# Playframework - JSON parsing object with single field - definition issue

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I cannot find a way how to make it work when deserialized object has single field - I cannot compile the code. Seems that `and` operator does some transformation and I cannot find a method to call to do the same.

I have following json:

```
{"total": 53, "max_score": 3.2948244, "hits": [
                                 {
                                     "_index": "h",
                                     "_type": "B",
                                     "_id": "3413569628",
                                     "_score": 3.2948244,
                                     "_source": {
                                         "fotky": [
                                             {
                                                 "popisek":" ",
                                                 "localFileSystemLocation":" ",
                                                 "isMain": true,
                                                 "originalLocation": ""
                                             }
                                         ]
                                     }
                                 }
                             ]
}
```

I try the following data model to de serialize to:

```
case class SearchLikeThisResult(total: Int, max_score: Double, hits: Seq[Hits])

case class Hits(_index: String, _type: String, _id: String, _score: Double, _source: Source)

case class Source(fotky: Seq[Photo])

case class Photo(isMain: Boolean, originalLocation: Option[String], localFileSystemLocation: Option[String], popisek: Option[String])
```

Implicit reads as follows:

```
object SearchLikeThisHits {

  import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

  implicit val photoReads: Reads[Photo] = (
    (JsPath \ "isMain").read[Boolean] and
      (JsPath \ "originalLocation").readNullable[String] and
      (JsPath \ "localFileSystemLocation").readNullable[String] and
      (JsPath \ "popisek").readNullable[String]
    )(Photo.apply _)    

  implicit val sourceReads: Reads[Source] = (
    (JsPath \ "fotky").read[Seq[Photo]]
    )(Source.apply _)

  implicit val hitsReads: Reads[Hits] = (
    (JsPath \ "_index").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "_type").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "_id").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "_score").read[Double] and
      (JsPath \ "_source").read[Source]
    )(Hits.apply _)

  implicit val searchLikeThisResult: Reads[SearchLikeThisResult] = (
    (JsPath \ "total").read[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "max_score").read[Double] and
      (JsPath \ "hits").read[Seq[Hits]]
    )(SearchLikeThisResult.apply _)
}
```

What I am really struggling with is under the _source:

```
  implicit val sourceReads: Reads[Source] = (
    (JsPath \ "fotky").read[Seq[Photo]]
    )(Source.apply _)
```

where read is reported as unkown symbol - in other cases `and` performs some transformation.
Inline definition doesn't help either.

Does anybody faced this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fancy applicative builder syntax (`and`, etc.) is nice, but it can obscure the fact that `Reads` is monadic and also works perfectly well with `map`, `flatMap`, `for`-comprehensions, etc.

So while the applicative builder syntax doesn't work with single values, plain old `map` does:

```
implicit val sourceReads: Reads[Source] =
  (JsPath \ "fotky").read[Seq[Photo]].map(Source(_))
```

The key here is that `(JsPath \ "fotky").read[Seq[Photo]]` is a `Reads[Seq[Photo]]`, and you want a `Reads[Source]`. `map` gives you a way to get from one to the other, just as you could use it to transform an `Option[Seq[Photo]]` into an `Option[Source`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could save yourself some trouble by making use of the `Json.reads` to automatically generate your `Reads` (provided the case class is defined exactly like the Json objects - which is your case).

```
implicit val photoReads = Json.reads[Photo]
implicit val sourceReads = Json.reads[Source]
implicit val hitsReads = Json.reads[Hits]
implicit val searchResultReads = Json.reads[SearchLikeThisResult]
```

For more information, see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJsonInception

Comment: This is reasonable advice but isn't necessarily a great answer—there are plenty of cases where the macro-provided instances won't work, and then you need to understand how to handle this situation without them.